# How to rewrite ui-gmap-marker to ui-gmap-markers?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I'm new to angular and the uiGmapGoogleMapApi and I'm trying to rewrite this:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="search.map.center" zoom="search.map.zoom" bounds="search.map.bounds" options="{ overviewMapControl: true, streetViewControl: false, mapTypeControl: false }">
    <locations ng-if="! search.isLoading" ng-repeat="player in search.results track by $index">
        <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="item in player.l track by $index" ng-if="item.g" idKey="$index" coords="{ latitude: item.g[0], longitude: item.g[1] }" options="{ labelContent: item.n }">
            <ui-gmap-window>
                <div>
                    <a ng-href="{[{ search.getplayerUrl(player) }]}">{[{ player.n }]}</a>
                    <p>{[{ player.s }]}</p>
                </div>
            </ui-gmap-window>
        </ui-gmap-marker>
    </locations>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

to the ui-gmap-markers.
Because the performance of ui-gmap-marker with ng-repeat is very bad.
I do not get ahead from this point. I don't get any errors.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="search.map.center" zoom="search.map.zoom" bounds="search.map.bounds" options="{ overviewMapControl: true, streetViewControl: false, mapTypeControl: false }">
    <locations ng-if="! search.isLoading" ng-repeat="player in search.results track by $index">
        <ui-gmap-markers models="player.l" idKey="id" coords="{ latitude: g[0], longitude: g[1] }" options="{ labelContent: n }" />
        <ui-gmap-window>
            <div>
                <a ng-href="{[{ search.getplayerUrl(player) }]}">{[{ player.n }]}</a>
                <p>{[{ player.s }]}</p>
            </div>
        </ui-gmap-window>
    </locations>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`coords` property must be a **string.**

[The document](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/markers) says:

> coords: string
>   The name of the property in the models array containing the marker
>   coordinates. Must refer to an object containing latitude and longitude
>   properties, or a GeoJSON Point object.

Comment: I think that is not the problem, the old version worked and they had the same requirements for the coords. The player contains something like that `"l": [
        {
          "df": 40.0, 
          "g": [
            48.1234567, 
            19.1234567
          ], 
          "l": 3
        }, 
        {
          "l": 2
        }
      ], 
      "m": "/....", 
      "n": "Name"`

Comment: `marker`'s `coords` property can be an object. But `markers`' must be a string. Read closely the difference between the two.